# How to dump large object or it's collection for debug in Symfony 2.6?

Tags: symfony

How can I dump doctrine collection in symfony2, as `var_dump` doesn't help me.
I tried following way.

1 - `print_r($records);`

2 - `var_dump($records);`

3 - `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($records);`

first two can't handle as result set is very large, and third one fail in some case. and other solution please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "The VarDumper Component" of symfony.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html

VarDumper component is by default available from Symfony2.6, so you just need to dump your collection like this.

```
dump($records);
```